# Make Fiware-Cygnus storing to Apache-Phoenix database

Tags: fiware, apache-phoenix, fiware-cygnus, sink

I'm new to Cygnus and to Phoenix db. I want Cygnus to store data in an Apache Phoenix db, so I have to configure the Phoenix Sink to work with Cygnus.

I know that Cygnus is an extension of Apache Flume, so any Flume agent can work with it by default (theoretically). I configured my Flume agent `agent_phoenix.conf` file for Cygnus like this:

```
cygnus-ngsi.channels = memoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = phoenix-sink

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = memoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5051
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf

cygnus-ngsi.channels.memoryChannel.type=memory
cygnus-ngsi.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity=100
cygnus-ngsi.channels.memoryChannel.byteCapacityBufferPercentage=20

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.type=org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.channel=memoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.batchSize=100
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.table=PROVA_PHOENIX
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.ddl=CREATETABLEIFNOTEXISTSPROVA_PHOENIX(uidVARCHARNOTNULL,f_hostVARCHARCONSTRAINTpkPRIMARYKEY(uid),colonnaProvaVARCHAR)
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.zookeeperQuorum=localhost
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.serializer=REGEX
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.serializer.rowkeyType=uuid
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.phoenix-sink.serializer.columns=colonnaProva
```

and launched it using this command on CentOS command line:

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_phoenix.conf -n cygnus-ngsi -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

It starts doing some initializations but then I get this message:

```
76666 [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] ERROR org.apache.phoenix.flume.serializer.BaseEventSerializer  - error No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost; occurred during initializing connection 
176667 [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] ERROR org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink  - Error No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost; in initializing the serializer.
176667 [lifecycleSupervisor-1-8] ERROR org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor  - Unable to start SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@29918f3 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost;
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
at org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink.start(PhoenixSink.java:124)
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost;
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.apache.phoenix.flume.serializer.BaseEventSerializer.initialize(BaseEventSerializer.java:140)
at org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink.start(PhoenixSink.java:119)
... 10 more
```

HBase and Phoenix are installed correctly on this machine, infact HBase can start and Phoenix has been tested with SQLline file. 
Do you have any solutions to this problem?

----EDIT----
I just made a step forward. I edited my `flume-env.sh` file inside cygnus/conf directory, and specified as FLUME_CLASSPATH the .jar file containing `PhoenixSink` java class. Now launching the same command that I wrote above it starts configuring (apparently well) then I get this error msg:

```
time=2017-10-30T22:27:40.552Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[142] : Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load sink type: org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink, class: org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:69)
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:415)
at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:103)
at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:67)
... 11 more
```

What is wrong now?

-------------EDIT 2-------------------

Ok I'm gettint closer, but this error has no sense. I solved the jdbc problem by copying the right phoenix JAR in classpath, then I got some dependecies errors and I solved them by copying other JARs in classpath. Now I get the same old error of jdbc. I really can't figure out what is happening:

```
[root@fiware fiware]# /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_phoenix.conf -n cygnus-ngsi -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /usr/cygnus/conf/flume-env.sh
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/phoenix-sink/:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/phoenix-sink/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/phoenix-sink/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_phoenix.conf -n cygnus-ngsi
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/phoenix-sink/lib/cygnus-ngsi-1.7.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.751Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp= | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[166] : Starting Cygnus, version 1.7.1.UNKNOWN
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.897Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.900Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.909Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_phoenix.conf
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.915Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.915Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.916Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.916Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.916Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.916Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.916Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.917Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.917Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.917Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[930] : Added sinks: phoenix-sink Agent: cygnus-ngsi
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.917Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=isValid | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[319] : Agent configuration for 'c' does not contain any channels. Marking it as invalid.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.919Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=validateConfiguration | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[127] : Agent configuration invalid for agent 'c'. It will be removed.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.934Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=validateConfiguration | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[140] : Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [cygnus-ngsi]
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.934Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=loadChannels | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[150] : Creating channels
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.944Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=create | msg=org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory[40] : Creating instance of channel memoryChannel type com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.949Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=loadChannels | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[205] : Created channel memoryChannel
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.951Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=create | msg=org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory[39] : Creating instance of source http-source, type org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.979Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=configure | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler[156] : [NGSIRestHandler] Startup completed
time=2017-10-31T06:59:24.994Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=create | msg=org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory[40] : Creating instance of sink: phoenix-sink, type: org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.247Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=getConfiguration | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[119] : Channel memoryChannel connected to [http-source, phoenix-sink]
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.255Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=startAllComponents | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{http-source=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{phoenix-sink=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@6be236d0 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{memoryChannel=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel{name: memoryChannel}} }
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.256Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=startAllComponents | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[145] : Starting Channel memoryChannel
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.258Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=register | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[110] : Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: memoryChannel, registered successfully.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.259Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[94] : Component type: CHANNEL, name: memoryChannel started
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.259Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=startAllComponents | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[173] : Starting Sink phoenix-sink
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.261Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink[116] : Starting sink Phoenix Sink__1 
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.268Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=register | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[110] : Monitoried counter group for type: SINK, name: Phoenix Sink__1, registered successfully.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.268Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=startAllComponents | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[184] : Starting Source http-source
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.268Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[94] : Component type: SINK, name: Phoenix Sink__1 started
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.273Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<init> | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.CygnusGroupingRules[49] : No grouping rules have been read. Details: /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf (No such file or directory)
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.287Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<init> | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.CygnusGroupingRules[49] : No grouping rules have been read. Details: /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf (No such file or directory)
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.412Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=register | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[110] : Monitoried counter group for type: SOURCE, name: http-source, registered successfully.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.412Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[94] : Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source started
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.460Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=initialize | msg=org.apache.phoenix.flume.serializer.BaseEventSerializer[200] : error No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost; occurred during initializing connection 
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.460Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink[123] : Error No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost; in initializing the serializer.
time=2017-10-31T06:59:25.462Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable[253] : Unable to start SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@6be236d0 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost;
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
at org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink.start(PhoenixSink.java:124)
at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:phoenix:localhost;
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.apache.phoenix.flume.serializer.BaseEventSerializer.initialize(BaseEventSerializer.java:140)
at org.apache.phoenix.flume.sink.PhoenixSink.start(PhoenixSink.java:119)
... 10 more
```

May someone explain this?

Comment: sounds like a path problem.  is the phoenix flume driver in the class path?

Comment: It may be that it isn't, I didn't do anything but configure agent and run the command, because theoretically Cygnus may work with every flume agent, and Phoenix is a flume agent. How should I add it?

Comment: I did like this because standing to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676814/adding-apache-flume-elastic-search-sink?rq=1) my configuration should work.

Comment: We (Cygnus developers team) have never test PhoenixDB integration with Orion CB through Cygnus, thus few can be said on our side. It must be something related to PhoenixDB sink itself. As you have said, Cygnus is just a wrapper for Apache Flume, thus using a third-party sink should be as simple as putting the proper .jar in the classpath and using it in the configuration...